# multiples token en laravel

Tags: php, vue.js, php7, tokens, laravel-8

Tengo un problema con 2 formularios y los `csrf_token()`.. acá la imagen de que quiero hacer:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto lo hago ajax

La aplicación **Registrarme** funciona correctamente
La aplicación **Iniciar sesión** me sale error: `419 CSRF token mismatch.`

Cuando elimino el formulario **Registrarme**, el otro formulario me funciona de maravilla, y si dejo ambos **Iniciar sesión** me tira error.

1- envio la ruta desde la plantilla, hacia Vuejs 
*desde el registro*

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="login_token" id="login_token">
<input type="text" @change="verify_email('{{ route('access.login.email') }}')" v-model="email_personal" class="form-control form-control-lg" required>
```

*desde el login*

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="register_token" id="register_token">
<button @click="register_now('{{ route('access.register') }}')" v-if="button_loading == false" class="btn btn-primary btn-modern float-right" type="button">registrarme</button>
```

2- atrapo las rutas y realizo la petición al servidor atravez del método post

*desde el registro*

```
register_now:function(url){
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('_token', this.token.value);
  this.$http.post(url, formData).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.body) //acá me saldría el resultado de la conexión
  });
```

*Desde el login*

```
verify_email:function(url){
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('_token', this.token.value);
  this.$http.post(url, formData).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.body) //acá me saldría el resultado de la conexión
  });
});
```

3- ahora atrapo esta petición mediante la ruta para asignarle un controlador a cada aplicación
*ambas rutas*

```
Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'verify'])->name('access.register');
Route::post('login/email', [LoginEmailController::class, 'verify'])->name('access.login.email');
```

4- desde el controlador opero con la información y retorno si la operación se realizó con éxito, o si hubo errores en distintas aplicaciones
*desde el login*

```
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        if (Usuarios::where('email', $request->email_personal)) {
            return ['success' => 'true'];
        }else{
            return ['error' => 'true'];
        }
    }
```

*desde el registro*

```
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        if (Usuarios::where('token' ,$request->token_personal)->first() && $request->token_personal != null) {
....
        }else{
            return ['response' => 'false', 'message' => 'Tu email personal ya exíste'];
        }
    }else{
        return ['response' => 'false', 'message' => 'Token no válido'];
    }
```

Los leo gracias

Comment: Adjuntá el código que utilizaste como un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), de lo contrario [pueden votarte negativamente porque solo decís que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855)

Comment: okey okey, ahi y adjunto el codigo

Comment: En el login, ¿estás obteniendo realmente el token?

Comment: no me vas a creer, me asegure de hacer los commits correspondientes con git, al volver a esta version empeze a tener problemas con el token, me fijo y no lo estaba recibiendo... increìble, perdi 5 horas por mi descuido, gracias por preguntar de no haberlo hecho no me habría percatado, realmente gracias